# Cypress choose what test file to launch based on a string

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am currently working in Cypress, I will try to semplify my question as much as possible:

I have several test files:

```
integration/testA.spec.js
integration/testB.spec.js
integration/testC.spec.js
```

I also have a `config.js` file in which I have an object containing the name of the test I want to run:

```
{
    test: 'testA.spec.js'
}
```

what I want to do - if possible - is a `main.spec.js` file that, depending on the `test`property, runs the relative spec file.

I have prepared almost everything

```
describe('Test', () => {
  before(() => {})

  beforeEach(() => {})

  after(() => {})

  describe('Test Booking', () => {
    // retrieves the `test`property and returns the string name
    let testName = retrieveTestName()
    console.log('testName', testName)

    /** I want to do something like this */
    if (testName === 'testA.spec.js') {
        // launch testA.spec.js file
    }
  }

})
```

but I ignore if I can do something like the code above; do you think is possible?

Or do I have to create a script file that

- checks for the namefile
- uses the `--spec` option and launches the test

?

Answer (score 0):

An option can be to create commands using the `--spec` file and add it under scripts in your `package.json`. Something like:

```js
"scripts": {
  "testA": "npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/testA.spec.js",
  "testB": "npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/testB.spec.js",
  "testC": "npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/testC.spec.js"
}
```

You can run directly run the above command depending on the test you want to execute.

```js
npm run testA
```